# Problems when I upload images and show them in angular and node using the GraphicsMagick

Tags: node.js, angular, sails.js

I use this code to upload images in Node:

```
req.file('image[]')
.upload({
  maxBytes: 5000000, // Files limit(in bytes)
  dirname: path.resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'assets/images/user') // Path to copy the files
}, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
  if (err) {
    // here must delete the created user before the error
    console.log(err);
  }
  var image_real_name = '';
  var json = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++){
    image_real_name = 'images/user/'+path.basename(uploadedFiles[i].fd);
    json.push(image_real_name);
  }
  res(json);
});
```

but I needed to compress the images to gain space on the server so I used the gm GraphicsMagick:

`

```
var receiver = new Writable({objectMode: true});
  receiver._write = function(file, enc, cb) {
    // The output stream to pipe to
    var output = require('fs').createWriteStream('assets/images/user/' + file.fd);
    gm(file).resize('200', '200').stream().pipe(output);
    cb();
  };
  req.file('image[]').upload(receiver, function(err, files){
    if (err) {
      // here must delete the created user before the error
      console.log(err);
    }
    var image_real_name = '';
    var json = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
      image_real_name = 'images/user/'+path.basename(files[i].fd);
      json.push(image_real_name);
    }
    res(json);
  });
```

`

I am using angular and when I change the direction of the image by binding the new image should be shown but it is not loaded, with the first code all perfect but using gm does not work anymore. I have to restart the page so that the image is displayed.

track:
  apparently the image has not been fully processed, if a setTime is entered, the image is displayed correctly:

```
setTimeout((dataService: DataService, image: any) => {
          dataService.getUser().image = image;
        }, 1000, this.data, dataI.json().url);
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a finish event when the file is fully loaded, I solved the problem by adding the following:

```
output.on("finish", function() { return cb(); });
```